# I have not been able to use the react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I try to make a simple application with react, mongodb and nodejs. I reached the point where I need to route the application and for this I use "BrowserRouter" just as a test I separated some code into a separate component and tried to call it as a label in my base code in the App.js file, however I don't get an answer of it. It works fine while I have the code inside the App.js file but not outside it.
from the browser in the terminal it only tells me that there is an error in the code that separates and only that.

App.js

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Add from './Add';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                {/*Navigation*/}
                <nav className="light-blue darken-4">
                    <div className="container">
                        <a className="brand-logo" href="/">Octopus</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/' component={Add}/>
                    </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Add.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Add extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <div className="container">

         </div>     
    )
  }
}


export default Add;
```

browser:

The above error occurred in the  component:
    in Add (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (created by App)
    in App

Comment: This question belongs to [PtSO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please post your question in english

Comment: PtSO is for Portuguese.  Try https://translate.google.com to translate Spanish questions into English.

Comment: Translated to english, code formatting